# How to sample pandas DataFrame with replacement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, size N. I need to sample it with S samples, with replacement where N < S.

```
def sampleDF(df, K): 
    return df.ix[np.random.randint(0, len(df), size=k)]
```

I return a new DF but it seems everything is filled with NaN. Am not sure what's going on!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `iloc[]`:

```
df.iloc[np.random.randint(0, len(df), size=k)]
```

Comment: works perfectly! Do you mind me asking why ix doesn't work - seems it did in smaller samples, but not in those with 5k rows

Comment: Here is the document: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix

Comment: This question came later but is more up to date:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061876/python-sampling-a-dataframe?rq=3