# Python sampling a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing dataframe 'products':

```
    Nr    Product  Verkoopprijs
0    1  Product A          1111
1    2  Product B          1320
2    3  Product C           727
3    4  Product D           783
4    5  Product E          1431
5    6  Product F           421
6    7  Product G           611
7    8  Product H          1244
8    9  Product I           952
9   10  Product J           856
10  11  Product K           660
11  12  Product L          1202
12  13  Product M           720
13  14  Product N          1046
14  15  Product O           980
15  16  Product P           679
16  17  Product Q          1049
17  18  Product R           874
18  19  Product S           430
19  20  Product T           781
20  21  Product U           772
21  22  Product V           806
22  23  Product W          1286
23  24  Product X           776
24  25  Product Y          1057
25  26  Product Z           545
```

Based on this I would like to create a new dataframe of 10000 rows, each row containing a random selected row from 'products'.

I use Pandas and Numpy

Comment: Did you try using pandas.DataFrame.sample? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Answer (score 2):

This answer belongs to @user1669710, if they choose to post an answer, select it as such.

Make sure to use `replace=True` because you're asking to take more random draws than there are things to draw from.

```
df.sample(10000, replace=True)
```

For display purposes.

```
df.sample(10, replace=True)

    Nr    Product  Verkoopprijs
25  26  Product Z           545
10  11  Product K           660
1    2  Product B          1320
16  17  Product Q          1049
3    4  Product D           783
23  24  Product X           776
0    1  Product A          1111
1    2  Product B          1320
19  20  Product T           781
```

if you want to `reset_index()`

```
df.sample(10, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True)

   Nr    Product  Verkoopprijs
0   4  Product D           783
1  21  Product U           772
2  24  Product X           776
3  19  Product S           430
4  16  Product P           679
5  19  Product S           430
6  15  Product O           980
7   4  Product D           783
8  12  Product L          1202
9  14  Product N          1046
```